# What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for a matrix to be a Gram matrix some of the scalar product?

Tags: linear-algebra

I met with a problem from linear algebra 2 semester in bachelor degree: What necessary and sufficient conditions are a square matrix a Gram matrix of some scalar product: a) in an n-dimensional real space; b) in n-dimensional complex space?

**Definition of Gram matrix**: $G(\upsilon_1, ..., \upsilon_n)$ is a Gram matrix (in basis $\upsilon_1, ..., \upsilon_n$) if it is a matrix of bilinear form ($G[i, j] = (\upsilon_i, \upsilon_j)$).

**Definition of scalar product**: Suppose $V$ - vector space, so $V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar product if: 1) Linearity: $\forall u_1,u_2, v \in V \ \alpha \in \R \ (u_1+\alpha u_2, v) = (u_1 ,v)+\alpha(u_2, v)$; 2) Symmetric: $\forall u, v \in V \ (u, v) = (v, u)$; 3) Positive certainty: $\forall u \in V \setminus \{\overline0\} \ (u, u) > 0$

I think we need to somehow consider the transitions from basis to basis and use the appropriate formula.

Comment: Why don't you start by editing to include the *definition* of the Gram matrix and a list of the properties you see from that definition?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I'm a newbie, thanks for the comment. Edited the post

Comment: Start with the real case. Maybe even start with the example of the standard scalar product on $\Bbb R^n$ and a different basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$. As you suggested, consider the change-of-basis matrix $A$ whose columns are the $v_j$. How do you give the Gram matrix in terms of $A$?

Comment: @TedShifrin To begin with, let's understand how the Gram matrix changes when moving from one basis to another: let $E = \{e_1, \dots, e_n\}, F=\{f_1, \dots, f_n\}$ be the bases of $V$ - a unitary space (columns!). Let $x\in V$ have coordinates $X = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, and $y \in V$ has coordinates $Y = (y_1, \dots, y_n)$ in the basis of $E$.

Comment: The relationship between the coordinates of the vector in different bases is determined by the following relations: $X=SX', Y=SY'$. Here $S$ is the transition matrix from the $E$ basis to the $F$ basis. $X', Y'$ are the coordinates of the vectors $x,y$ in the basis $F$, respectively. Then we know that $(x,y) = X^TG_E\overline Y =(X')^TG_F\overline{Y'}$.

Comment: Then we get that $(X')^TG_F \overline{Y'} = (SX')^TG_E\overline{(SY')} = (X')^TS^TG_E\overline{S} \cdot \overline{Y'}$. А значит $ g_f = s ^ TG_E \ overline {s}$. 

Next, I claim that the square matrix $G$ is a Gram matrix for some set of linearly independent vectors $\Longleftrightarrow$ $\exist$ non-degenerate matrix $S:G=S^T\cdot\overline{S}$.

Comment: OK. It's still probably easier to stick with the real case first. If $G=S^\top S$ for an invertible $S$, what properties does this matrix have? Two should be clear. Now the question is, can you go backwards? It's hard for us to know what knowledge you have to prove this.

Comment: @TedShifrin I think that G is invertible and G is symmetric. But for scalar product, we need yet another properties such as 1) Linearity and 3) Positive certainity

Comment: $G=S^\top S$ *is* positive definite (that's the English term). If you define a bilinear form on a basis, then how is it defined for all vectors?

Comment: Suppose $e_1, ..., e_n$ is basis. B is a bilinear form and $A$ is matrix of bilinear form: $A = B(e_i, e_j)$. So $\forall x, y \in V: B(x, y) = x^T A y$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133421/discussion-between-n2k-and-ted-shifrin).